# Saving QGIS form design basic functionality in .ui to modify it with QTDesigner

Tags: qgis-3, qt-designer

It is possible to save a classic Qgis form (a drag and drop form) in order to modify it with QtDesigner afterwards ?

I have created a form and I just want to change a list value into a toggle button but I don't find the way to save the form in .ui format.

I am using QGIS 3.4.5.

Answer (score 2):

When you use drag and drop form, QGIS simply store it as XML in the QML/QGS using the XML format. You can't get back a UI file.

It depends what you are trying to do, but you can add Python logic.

Comment: What I understand is that, to use QtDesigner (ex : put a toggle button instead of a list value for one attribute), I have to re-create the form completly (for the other attributes too) and then add some python logic if necessary ?