# Transfer QGIS form from Drag and Drop Designer to QT

Tags: qgis, qt-designer

I want to take the form designed using the drag and drop designer in QGIS, into Qt Designer to modify it further and then bring it back into QGIS. Is this possible?

As per
[Saving QGIS form design basic functionality in .ui to modify it with QTDesigner](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/338672/saving-qgis-form-design-basic-functionality-in-ui-to-modify-it-with-qtdesigner)

I understand that QGIS can only export QML and not .ui files.

Is there some other way of connecting the 2 or do I need to start from scratch in QT?